# Propositional Logic, P or Q but not both.

Tags: propositional-calculus

If I had two propositions, P and Q, and wanted to write an expression such that either P or Q are true but not both, what would be the best notation for it?

Comment: $$P\bar Q+\bar PQ$$  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Comment: Wikipedia has a nice roundup at the end of this paragraph after some explanations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_disjunction#Equivalencies.2C_elimination.2C_and_introduction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way in terms of the most common connectives would be
$$(P \wedge \neg Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q)$$
You could bash this with de Morgan's laws: $P \wedge \neg Q$ is equivalent to $\neg (P \to Q)$ and $\neg P \wedge Q$ is equivalent to $\neg (Q \to P)$, so we can write this as
$$\neg (P \to Q) \vee \neg (Q \to P)$$
which is itself equivalent to
$$(P \to Q) \to \neg (Q \to P)$$
I don't really know why you'd want to do this though, I'm just listing some options for you to choose from!

Sometimes this is expressed with an 'xor' operator $\oplus$, in which case it's simply
$$P \oplus Q$$
but this notation is much less widespread than $\wedge\ \vee\ \neg\ \to$.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Comment: You could add to this list the (probably shortest without defining something new) form $\neg (P\leftrightarrow Q)$. Not very intuitive or particularly useful though...

Answer (score 3):

The most common term is "exclusive or", abbreviated "xor".

As for logical notation, just translating what you said does nicely. Two ways of writing it would be
$$
(P\lor Q)\land\lnot(P\land Q)\\
(\lnot P \land Q) \lor (P\land \lnot Q)
$$

Comment: Nice and simple, thank you.